# How can I remove the leading comma from my data write?

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6

I am trying to write an MD array to a csv file, but I am getting a leading comma starting on line 2.
Here is the method:

```
writeDataFile(dataPath, data, COLUMNS) {
  const FS = require('fs');
  let finalData = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < COLUMNS; j++) {
      if (j < COLUMNS - 1) {
        finalData.push(data[i][j]);
      } else {
        finalData.push(data[i][j]+ '\n');
      }
    }
    finalData[i] = finalData[i].replace(/(^,)|(,$)/g, "");
    let fileHandle = FS.writeFileSync(dataPath, finalData, 'utf8');
  }
}
```

And here is sample output:

```
User,One,101
,User,Two,102
,User,Three,103
```

And this is the MD array:

```
[[User][One][101]]
[[User][Two][102]]
[[User][Three][103]]
```

Comment: Could you please share what this function takes in as input? What values are passed into `dataPath`, `data`, `COLUMNS` when this scenario occurs?

Comment: I update the above question to include the array.

Comment: You need to include your code in backticks, friend. Otherwise it isn't very clear as SO strips out all the braces.

Comment: You realise that the `finalData` you're passing into `writeFileSync` is an array?

Comment: @Bergi - Yes, is that bad?

Comment: @BackPacker777: It's the reason you're getting commas between all the array elements. Can you explain how you designed this code to work? I find it especially troublesome that you're doing things to `finalData[i]` (which is unrelated to the current loop iteration) and that you're repeatedly overwriting your file in the loop.

Comment: @Bergi - I wanted the commas in between the elements, just not at the front or end or the written lines. I left the finalData[i] line in there so folks could see that I had attempted to use .replace.

Comment: The commas are not (and never were) parts of the elements of `finalData`. They're added when the [array is converted into a string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toString) to be written to the file.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I did it:

```
writeDataFile(dataPath, data, COLUMNS) {
          const FS = require('fs');
          for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
               let line = "";
               for (let j = 0; j < COLUMNS; j++) {
                    if (j < COLUMNS - 1) {
                         line = line + data[i][j] + ',';
                    } else {
                         line = line + data[i][j] + '\n';
                    }
               }
               let fileHandle = FS.appendFileSync(dataPath, line, 'utf8');
          }
     }
```